# Notify participant with a message to start another flow

Tags: corda

Good day.

I encounter a problem regarding messages sending and receiving. Scenario is as follow

Node: A and B

Flow: P and Q

Flow P has one participant A

Flow Q has two participants A and B

Flow Q will be triggered multiple times. Each time when Q is finished, I want to send a message to node A and start Flow P with a message including an identifier info.

I thought send() can do this but I cannot figure out how. Do I need to run Flow P first and suspend it with received() and wait for a message from Flow Q?

Comment: When Flow Q finishes, are you trying to start Flow P from node A or node B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start flow P as a sub flow from flow Q, before flow Q finishes.

Comment: what to do if we want to start flow P as subflow in flow Q but its triggered from Node A (another node)? because until now, i just figure out start flow P as subflom but triggered from Node B